# Compare char in linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

How can i compare a char value in linq. what i am doing is not working , can anyone suggest me what is wrong with my code.
my column is

> public char MarketingType { get; set; }

and the size of the column in database is 1

```
public List<Marketing> MarketVideo { get; set; }
var debs = from s in iMarketingService.GetMarketingContents()
                           select s;
viewModelMarketing.MarketVideo = debs.Where(t => t.MarketingType =='v').ToList();
```

above condition is not working and showing me the empty list but when i compare it with other integer type column like below it is working fine for me.

```
viewModelMarketing.MarketVideo = debs.Where(t => t.AddeddBy == 2).ToList();
```

any suggestions , or help will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Is it perhaps an upper-case `V`?

Comment: What database are you using?  I think that `CHAR(1)` means a __string__ of length one, not an individual `char`.  So a `char` comparison is out-of-place.

Comment: @Jamiec no it is lower-case v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i guess char 1 means a string of length one.

so you can change it to

```
public string MarketingType { get; set; }
```

and your condition should be

```
debs.Where(t => t.MarketingType.Equals("v")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public List<Marketing> MarketVideo { get; set; }
var debs = from s in iMarketingService.GetMarketingContents()
                       select s;
viewModelMarketing.MarketVideo = debs.Where(t => t.MarketingType.ToLowerInvariant() =="v").ToList();
```

Comment: i am getting an error no overload for method ToLowerInvariant() takes 0 argument

Comment: Try with : .ToLower() instead... But it's strange btw